# Wordpress links within a page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to implement bookmarks/inline page linking to my wordpress page.

I have tried the simple rule in the wordpress page editor.

```
<p id="name1">.....................</p>
```

and call it using this following link

```
<a href=#name1> Go to name1 </a>
```

But it does not work. It stays at the same location though the URL has been updated with #name1 suffix

Comment: Is the `<p id="name1">.....................</p>` visible on the screen when you click the link? If it is, nothing will happen, it should scroll there if it's not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<a href=#name1> Go to name1 </a>

<h1 name="name1"></h1>
<p>.....................</p>
```

Personally I recommend anchoring to the header, not the paragraph as that's a bitt messy.